# Interal Server Error 500 - session_start()

Tags: php, facebook, internal-server-error

Well, I found quite a lot of threads with **ISE 500**, but none of the solutions worked for me.

I developed a facebook app for our client to present some audiotracks and, of course, would like to pass some parameters to the application per app_data param. So I integrated the **facebook sdk 3.1.1.** did everything to connect properly to facebook.

On my local xampp everythings works fine, our companys webserver also runs the application without any problems, so does my private webspace. But when I upload the application to the clients server I get a 500: Internal Server Error. To rule out any weird scripting errors on my side I tried to execute the example.php that comes with the sdk. Same error. Even when I just tried to instantiate the Facebook class like this:

```
<?php

require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '???',
  'secret' => '??????',
));
?>
```

I already looked at the servers error logs. The only thing it mentions is this:

**"Premature end of script headers: example.php"**

I also used the widely suggested `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to avoid wrong errorhandling on the serverside. Nothing. The server just wont tell me whats wrong.

I found quite a lot of reasons why other people got this error, the most prominent ones:

- Missing `?>` tag in the facebook.php / base_facebook.php
- Multiple instances of the `Facebook`- and `FacebookApiException`

...none of the provided solutions worked for me.

So I tried to compare the phpinfos of both, the client and our companys server. Of course there were some differences, but nothing obvious to me. I looked for the basic things people at the forums had already associated with a ISE 500 like the **cURL extension**, **php version (5.3.9)**. I am not a server-admin, I only got a very basic knowledge of server configurations. So to be sure that something is missing i tried to find server requirements for the facebook sdk...

...but the whole web won't tell me server requirements for the facebook sdk. Even the facebook documentation doesn't mention anything. So i hope there might be someone around here who can help me with this.

And yes... i already asked the server-admin for help, he just looked at me with two questionmarks in his eyes... and yes... i have to use the clients server :( *sigh*

Thanking you in anticipation...

---

**UPDATE:**
I will list the things i tried in response to your suggestions:

Server:
- cURL extension is installed (7.20.1)
- php version is 5.3.9.
- tried to include other files, works fine. Doesnt seem to be a path-problem
- Server error logs just show "Premature end of script headers: example.php"
- log_errors is enabled. error_log says 'no value'
- tried `ini_set("display_errors", true);` for bug tracking... no effect

---

**UPDATE 2**

So I was able to identify the problem after checking the facebook files row by row. The Internal Server Error 500 is thrown right at the start after trying to start a session:

```
if(!session_id())
{
    session_start();
}
```

I forwarded this info to the server-admin and the client... i guess its out of my hands now, i will update this post when i get an answer. Thanks for your feedback guys :)

---

**SOLUTION**

Ok the server-admin now identified the problem. The session.save_handler was set to 'user', He changed it to 'files', now everything works.:

```
session.save_handler = files
```

Thanks again for help!

Comment: Maybe it's stupid to ask, but still have to. ) Did you try to run the simplest php-scripts at your customer's server, like the infamous `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` one? It'll be very interesting to check the PHP version and the modules loaded, by the way.

Comment: well, i thought there are no stupid questions :D but yes of course, like i wrote, this was the first thing i tried, php version is suitable (5.3.9)

Comment: And i would be grateful if anyone could tell we what the facebook sdk needs to run properly (what extension like cURL for example)

Comment: Try requiring another php file that is next to facebook.php... one you just make.  See if it's a path problem, or something specific to the copy of facebook.php you have.

Comment: Did you check the information of phpinfo(), was the curl extension installed?

Comment: @MichaelPryor Just did that, doesn't seem to be the problem :(

Comment: @Pekka Hi Pekka, as I mentioned in my question, the server logs didn't log anything other than "Premature end of script headers: example.php"

Comment: @Acure ah, sorry, I overread that.

Comment: Look at the output of phpinfo and note down the values of `log_errors`  (must be on) and `error_log`. Locate the file referenced by error_log and see if you find any errors logged by the PHP engine in _that_ file.

Comment: @SalmanA log_errors is enabled but error_log says 'no value'. So i guess i have to ask the serveradmin to specify a output file/folder?

Comment: Very good question. I am still getting the problem. I will try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phpinfo() had the answer. Under session, the save_handler parameter had to be set from:

**`session.save_handler = user`**

to:

**`session.save_handler = files`**

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this at the top of your script, before your include:

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't show anything, just the same "500: Internal Server Error" :(

Comment: Try adding a php_value directive through an htaccess file in the site root setting the display_errors value

Comment: I solved setting memory_limit to 256M in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example of exceptionally bad question.

While the only your problem is `how to get an error message from PHP`, you wrote a whole novel on the things nobody needs to know. It doesn't matter if you run a facebook app or anything else. It doesn't matter what version curl you have installed.

The only thing you need is PHP error message.
You have to track it down. 
Check `error_reporting`, `error_log` and `log_errors` directives in phpinfo().
Check user's home directory for the additional log files. Ask server admin for the log files. THIS have to be the only direction of your search - a PHP error message.

Comment: I'm very sorry and will keep this in mind, in the future i will keep it short and to the point :( Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this problem myself.  It turns out my PHP error log file in (c:/windows/temp) was over 36 GB in size.  I deleted the error log file and the 500 error went away.

Not sure why that was a problem, but I'm guessing it ran into some kind of limitation.